# Reading matrix from text file c

Tags: c, matrix, segmentation-fault, text-files

when compiling with gcc i get the error message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" but i can't find the point where i access out of bound memory. I even tried to only fill the matrix partially but as always after I successfully read all values from file i get the same error message. The error triggers after reading the last element

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NR 4
#define NC 8
#define FILENAME "../debug.log"

int ndominanti(int [][NC], int);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    
    int info[NR][NC];
    FILE * pf;
    int i, j, ris;

    if(pf = fopen(FILENAME, "r")){

        for(i = 0; i < NR; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < NC; j++)
                fscanf(pf, "%d", &info[i][j]);
    /* this is where the error occurs */

        fclose(pf);

        ris = ndominanti(info, NR);
        printf("ris: %d\n", ris);
    }else
        printf("Errore apertura file %s\n", FILENAME);

    return 0;
}

int ndominanti(int info[][NC], int nrighe){
    int i, j, k, h;
    int curr, ndom, nrighedim, ncoldim;
    int isdom;

    nrighedim = nrighe - 1;
    ncoldim = NC - 1;
    ndom = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < nrighedim; i++)
        for(j = 0; i < ncoldim; j++){
            curr = info[i][j];
            isdom = 1;
            for(k = i + 1; k < nrighe && isdom; k++)
                for(h = j + 1; h < NC && isdom; h++)
                    if(curr <= info[k][h])
                        isdom = 0;
            if(isdom)
                ndom++;
        }

    return ndom;
}
```

here's the content of the file debug.log each line is separated by CRLF while single elements are separated by single space and there's a CRLF at the end

```
5 9 2 4 1 7 2 4
3 5 6 2 5 6 1 2
1 3 4 7 8 8 3 0
1 3 5 6 7 8 2 1
```

Comment: You get a segmentation fault when compiling?

Comment: Did you mean "for(j = 0; **j** < ncoldim; j++)"?

Comment: `for(j = 0; i < ncoldim; j++)` -> `for(j = 0; j < ncoldim; j++)`

Comment: Tip: Use a debugger. Seems like you don't actually know the exact line that triggers the seg fault. A debugger can give you that info instantly and can also be used to examine the variables.

Comment: Another thing: Write your programs in English.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica - is this comment supposed to be a joke? There is a single output message in another language.

Comment: @enhzflep No, it was not a joke. It is better to use English identifiers and write English comments. Because, you know, faster than you thought you will be collaborating with an international community whose *lingua franca* is English. I'm currently working for a large German company whose code base is partly in German which sometimes seriously hinders the international cooperation which has intensified in the past years. So, every programmer needs to be sufficiently proficient in English to use it in their programs and documents. **If they aren't, they must become it.** Start now.

Answer (score 0):

i'm sorry but i couldn't figure out the issue and it was driving me nuts anyway all i took was this

```
for(j = 0; i < ncoldim; j++) -> for(j = 0; j < ncoldim; j++)
```

thank you @kaylum

i wasn't checking the function because i thought the problem was inside the main since i couldn't execute any command after the point i marked in the code (way before i call the function)